# Making a slideshow with navigation without javascript

Tags: html, css, slideshow, responsive-images

I need help figuring out what in the code is going wrong. You can see it below. I tried following style guides on here, and nothing seemed to work. Please help, as this is for class. I have to use visual studio code as my html/css builder. I cannot upload my CSS because it keeps recognizing it as invalid code, but here is what I have:

html:

```
<div class="slidershow middle">

<div class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="rl" checked>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
<div class="slide s1">
<img src="images/Making_Pasta.jpg" alt="Making_Pasta">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/noodles.jpg" alt="noodles">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/pasta.jpg" alt="pasta">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/pesto.jpg" alt="pesto">
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="images/flatbread.jpg" alt="flatbread">
</div>
</div>
        
<div class="navigation">
<label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
<label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS

Comment: You can test the validity of your code through something like the W3C validator. It is not clear what your question is. You need to show us your CSS (are you sure you can't get it into a snippet - use the <> sign when you edit) and then describe what you had hoped your code would do and what it actually is doing.